# C Programming with Cygwin and gdbtui

Tags: c, gdb, cygwin

my question is regarding to the use of Cygwin and gdb. I was working on a school project but they want me to practice without the use of Visual Studio or similar compilers.

My questions is.. How would I be able to code C? Would this be on a text program or on Cygwin itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE may arguably be considered too close to Visual Studio, but until you learn the in's and out's of it, it's really just a place to write and compile code. You can keep to the spirit of the request by just using it as such rather than digging into its full capabilities.

If you really need to do it from scratch, use any text editor (eg: Notepad) and manually compile like this: http://ce.uml.edu/compile.htm

Comment: Ok. I understand. I guess I will either software to code and save as a .c file then compile with Cygwin.

Comment: oh wow.. that link is amazing. Thank you for the post. This is probably all I needed to start and finish.

Comment: @numbplum: you're welcome. BTW: welcome to Stack Overflow. When you find the answer which best addresses your question (by me or by anyone else) please click the check mark to "accept" it as your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can write program using any good text editor like [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-free-or-open-source-text-editors-for-developers/1031).

If you have cygwin installed on your system then you can just add c/c++ compiler (like gcc) to it and compile the program.

You always need not to use IDE for writing and compilation of programs.

Answer (score 1):

Even though @Dinah does answer your question we still have not discussed about the way to use the gdb debugger .

Since you are starting out new i suggest you master debugging using a debugger like gdb . Believe me you will save tonnes of time figuring out what went wrong using print statements ( or any other equivalent mechanisms )

Here is a good place where you can start [learn to use gdb](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/)

Have fun!